# UIActivityIndicatorView between ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

In my `FirstViewController`, there is an `IBAction` that call to `SecondViewController`.

`SecondViewController` in his `ViewDidLoad` loads an array from an server, for this reason the time of transition between `FirtsViewController` and `SecondViewController` is so long.

I would like put an `UIActivityIndicatorView` in `FirstViewController` that it will animating when `IBAction` y push, and stop when the transition between views is finish.

¿Some idea?

Thanks for all.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load the data asynchronously. Something like:

```
// second view controller
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // show loading activity (e.g. UIActivityIndicatorView)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self loadDataFromServer];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // hide loading activity and refresh view with loaded data
        });
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to add activity indicator either on the firstViewController or on the secondViewController.

Or Another option is put a timer to load second view controller like this,

```
-(void)viewDidLoad    
{       
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(firstAPICall) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];    
}
```

From the above line of code the screen will immediately navigate and and then load the data from server. Using the "firstAPIcall" method.

Answer (score 0):

Write the server call in a separate method. In the `viewDidLoad` of your second View controller, call this server method on the background thread. And start showing a view with an activity indicator. Meanwhile in the server method, once the call is complete, make a call to a callback method on the main thread which hides the activity indicator and display the required things on your second view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to put an overall view with activity indicator, above all the views so no matter which view is being presented the activity indicator will always be presented.
To do so, you need to create an transparent view with activity indicator, you can read about that here:
http://ramin.firoozye.com/2009/09/29/semi-modal-transparent-dialogs-on-the-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this :

In your SecondViewController's `viewDidLoad`

on .h file

```
@interface SecondViewController 
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView;

@end
```

in .m file

```
@synthesize activityView;

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    self.activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 80, 30, 30)];
           self.activityView.hidesWhenStopped = YES ;
    [self addSubview:activityView];
    activityView.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    [activityView startAnimating];

    [self performSelector:@selector(getData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

}

- (void) getData
{
   // code for server call
   .
   .
   // as downloading get complited

    [self.activityView stopAnimating]
}
```